# How to install FHIR Listener in Mirth Connect

Tags: hl7-fhir, mirth, mirth-connect

I am using Mirth Connect v3.5.1.Tried to install FHIR Listener,throws error(refer attachment).

I am struggling from the past 3hr?

I am using Ubuntu-14.04 and Java 8.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've just installed the plugin, you may need to clear your Java cache and then relaunch from the 8080 launch page. You can do so through the Java Control Panel (make sure to check all boxes in the Delete Temp Files dialog), or you can do `javaws -uninstall` on the command line.

Comment: thnk yu @Nick. Its working after restarting my machine.